# If we can see temperature by a thermometer

Tags: abstract-nouns, concrete-nouns

Temperature is an abstract noun because we cannot sense it per se. If we can see temperature by a thermometer, does temperature become a concrete noun?

Comment: I don't think that it makes any real difference whether a noun is abstract or concrete.

Comment: "Temperature is an abstract noun because we cannot sense it per se. " - who says?

Comment: We can _feel_ a change in temperature, but we can only _measure_ it with a thermometer. That still doesn't make temperature a solid object, though!

Comment: You can't see a *temperature* on a thermometer, you can only see a *temperature reading*.